# Regex to extract a word from a bunch of strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match and extract the state names from the following strings.

```
Example format: Country\State\City
USA\NY\NYC (desired output = NY)
USA\NY (desired output = NY)
USA\WA (desired output = WA)
USA\NY\ALBANY (desired output = NY)
USA\WA\SEATTLE (desired output = WA)
```

The regex I have so far is https://regex101.com/r/Ltwuup/3 but I have no idea what I'm doing and appreciate any help.

Comment: What language or tool is this for?

Comment: Honestly, there's probably a less resource intensive way to retrieve these using basic string manipulation if you're showing us the entire string.

Comment: I need this regex for some Excel data cleanup I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is PHP because when opening your link I saw that it's set to PHP flavor regex.

In this case:

```
\w+\\(\w{2})\\
```

Should work.
This takes any word characters (the country) before the single backslash (escaped), then takes any 2 letter state code (word characters) and matches it into group 1, then terminates with the next backslash it encounters.  Then you can reference group 1 and have NY, WA, NC, etc.

Comment: What would I do if I want to extract state as I mentioned above but some data entries look like:

USA\NY, 
USA\NY\ALBANY, 
USA\WA, 
USA\WA\SEATTLE

Comment: `\w+\\(\w{2}).*` Should do it.  That just tells it that you don't need a backslash afterwards, and it can be anything (including nothing).